# R QCCPackage shwehart Rules

Tags: r

I´m working with [Quality Control Charts - qcc R package](http://cran.r-project.org/package=qcc). I need to now how to edit shwehart rules. This is, how can I change the default 8 rules? I see the functions rules, Shewhart.rules, but I can't understand it.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure what you mean by the "8 default rules", but the qcc function takes arguments that will affect what the various data-driven calculations  on a process run will return. The "nsigmas" and "confidence.level"  are the two that would be the most influential in determining the UCL and LCL for a process. Beyond that, if you editted the data-input you could further affect what would get passed to the two function that shewhart.rules() calls but that would be violating the assumptions underlying the whole effort. You can also change the "type" argument to omit one or more of c("xbar", "R", "S", "xbar.one", "p", "np", "c", "u", "g").